# Converter value de um componente select options em number

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Tenho um componente `select` e gostaria de converter os `value` para o formato `Number` pois quando eu for salvar eu preciso de um valor `2` e não assim `"2"`

o ideal seria converter todas as `tag` `<option>`

```
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
              <label class="lb">Tipo docto liquidação:</label> 
              <select ng-model="notaLiquidacao.idTipoDoctoLiquidacao"  class="form-control" >
                <option  value=2>Nota Fiscal de Produtor</option> 
                <option  value=3>Nota Fiscal</option>
                <option  value=4>Contranota de Venda</option>
                <option  value=6>DANFE</option>                   
              </select>

            </div>
```

Comment: Já tentou [`parseInt`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)?

Comment: Tentei mas não consegui converter todos os `value`

Comment: por se tratar de angular... se você tem o atributo tipado na sua model, teoricamente ele já deveria interpretar o value como number

Comment: sim, mas quando eu pego a informação do objeto é no formato String

Answer (score 0):

Use o `parseInt()`

```
<script>
  var meuNumber =  parseInt($(".form-control").val());
</script>
```